# Retrieve each values in the Div

Tags: jquery

This piece of code will loop for several time.

When any user select any of the radio button I want to find which radio button is selected.

With the selected index I want to get `address_<selectedIndex> object;`. Now I want to access its siblings div values like addressLine_1, addressLine_2, addressLine_3, city, state, zip in a variable.

Please help to me write this piece of jQuery script.

```
<div class="address">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="8%" align="center"><input type="radio" name="addressSelected"  value="1" /></td>
        <td class="address_0" width="92%">
            <div class="addressLine_1">gotomedia LLC</div>
            <div class="addressLine_2">2169 FOLSOM ST</div>
            <div class="addressLine_3">STE M301</div>
            <div class="city floatLeft">SAN FRANCISCO</div>
            <div class="state floatLeft">&nbsp;CA</div>
            <div class="zip floatLeft">&nbsp;94110</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more code, preferably something that includes the radio buttons you're talking about.

Comment: SO is willing to *help* with your homework, but we're not going to *do* it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be your solution.
You have to watch out for the value of the input field as this code checks `$(this).val() == "1"`. Maybe you have to modify it.

```
var values = [];
$("input[name=addressSelected]:checked")
  .filter( function () { return $(this).val() == "1"  } )
  .parent()           // the parent td
  .siblings()         // the other tds
  .children("div")    // the divs
  .each( function () { values.push ( $(this).text ) } );
```

That should do the trick

You might change the each line:

```
 .each( function () { values[ this.className ] = $(this).text } );
```

so you can access it like: `values['addressLine_1']` however you would have to remove your float classes for a good result